# trace a route avoiding a street

Tags: google-maps, routes, gps, geolocation

¿is't possible to trace a route with GPS location from point A (the GPS location of user) to point B (a marker given by the user), ¡¡but!!, avoiding a street on google maps API?

i have half of this, i know how to trace A to B with GPS location on google maps api doing a click on some button, but im not sure if i can avoid some street.

[This is an example of what i want to do, assuming the blue marked street is the one that i cant cross](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZhP7.jpg)

Comment: Not possible with the Google Maps APIs at present.  [Enhancement request in the issue tracker: Issue 214: Ability to influence Directions (e.g. "avoid" / "roadblock")](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=214)

Comment: too bad...

is there a way to achieve this with another plataform?